# How do you use Flexbox to fill all the empty space on the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my code :

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <p>This is a test!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this just creates a box that says "This is a test!" and underneath the pink box is just a bunch of empty white space. I want the flex box to completely fill everything under it with pink. How do I do this?

I already tried align-items: stretch, and a billion other methods but I just can't seem to get it to work.

I am still new to flexbox so please let me know if I may be missing some fundamental.

Comment: The code that you gave seems to miss a `</div>`. I think it's just you miss it when copy/paste, so I add it in the snippet. *But*, I suggest you to make the snippet exactly show the "fill everything under it", and so with others tag that you have and to be more precise when helping you

Answer (score 1):

add the background-color directly to the flex-container. Also you should add a `min-height` like `min-height: 100vh`. By default the flex-container will only use a aheight to fit-content.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;  
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <p>This is a test!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, you have moved the background color to the parent element, instead of having it in the ".main" as it was in the original question. Maybe you can add an explanation for that?

Comment: @Chique because the background-color applies to the child element. As such the background-color will not stretch to fill the entire parent but only the size of the child element. If you let the child element stretch to fill out the entire parent element. But then both `justify-content` and align-items` will become useless. the text will then not be centered anymore but sit in the top-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

So in order for the children `.main` div to stretch full height, the parent `.content` needs to have a defined height. Easiest way to do this, is to add a min-height (minimum height) to it. In your case, you want it to stretch across the entire page if I got you right, so we add a minimum height of 100vh. Here "vh" unit stands for viewport height ([more on CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)).

Now that we have made the content go full height, there are 2 ways to make the child `.main` div cover the entire area of the "flexbox" .content. Either you use `align-items: stretch` on the `.content` (parent), or you can use `align-self: stretch` on the child `.main`.

Here I have used the 2nd option. Both works same in your case, but if you need to place other items, then you might choose one over the other method.

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height:100vh;
}

.main {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: pink;
    align-self:stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
        <p>This is a test!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: If you run the example here, you might see there is a white border around the pink area, which is coming from the `body` of HTML having a default padding/margin. To get rid of this, you can add a `padding:0; margin:0;` on the `body` element. But this isn't related to your actual question or solution.